# JS Analytics Ecommerce callback

Tags: javascript, google-analytics, e-commerce, google-analytics-api

I couldn't find anywhere how to use `hitCallback` parameter with google analytics `ecommerce:send`. In docs its only example is with `send,pageview`.

Here is the code I tried:

```
ga('ecommerce:send',
   {'hitCallback': function() {window.location.href="/test.php";}}
);
```

but it didn't work although the tracking worked.

Comment: It's possible that ga('ecommerce:send') doesn't support additional parameters, although I couldn't find any evidence to support this claim. I will test tomorrow when I'm at work.

Comment: Thank you, I wonder if there is any command like `ga('send','ecommerce',...)`

Comment: I haven't been able to test, but I took another look at Google's documentation and noted that the send method only supports these values i.e. pageview, event, social, and timing. Further documentation here - https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/method-reference#send

Comment: I added the `hitCallback` event to the `ecommerce:addTransaction` and it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ran in to the same problem and, having looked at the source code, there's no clean way to do it.

The thing about `ga('ecommerce:send')` is that internally it calls -

- `ga('send', 'transaction', {...})` once for your transaction, then
- `ga('send', 'item', {...})` once for each item

If you *have* to wait for your `ecommerce:send` to complete you could do one of the following:

1. Hack a custom `ecommerce.js` that allows you to pass in a `hitCallback` function, or
2. Google Analytics uses `<img/>` tags to send data if it's less than 2KB. So, you could check every `<img/>` tag that is created by JavaScript, and if the `src` attribute contains www.google-analytics.com then wait for it to load.

I've actually used #2 successfully (see http://jsfiddle.net/zkQXX/), but it really is a hack.

Answer (score 3):

As mentioned, hitCallback doesn't work for ecommerce:send. Craziness.

However, what I found (today at least) is that it *does* work for ecommerce:addTransaction and ecommerce:addItem (for when they are finally sent). Therefor you just have to make sure that all your hitCallbacks from those calls have been hit and then you're safe.

Comment: I've been working all day on this and just came to this conclusion before finding this question which confirms it. Crazy. It's almost 2016 and this still works. I used it in ecommerce:addItem and it works great. Thanks!